# Class bound function python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In python 2 I could create a class bound method using:

```
types.MethodType(func, None, cls)
```

However in python3 MethodType does not take the 3rd parameter.

How can I achieve the same behaviour in python 3? Preferably in a way that is still valid in python2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in Python3, you don't need to use `MethodType` anymore to create class bound methods (though you still need it to assign instance bound methods). Thus if you're going to do this:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
# end of class definition
# ...
# whoops I forgot a method for A
def foo(self, *args):
  pass
```

You can later attach `foo` to `A` using just `A.foo = foo`. (In Python2 you had to use `A.foo = types.MethodType(foo, None, A)` or such.)

If you want to add `foo` just to a particular instance of `A`, you would still use `MethodType`, although (in Python3) only with two arguments:

```
a = A()
a.foo = types.MethodType(foo, a)
```

(In Python2, you had to use `a.foo = types.MethodType(foo, a, A)` or such.)

As far as I can see, if you want a strategy that works with both versions, you'd have to do something like this:

```
try:
  A.foo = types.MethodType(foo, None, A)
except TypeError:
  # too many arguments to MethodType, we must be in Python3
  A.foo = foo
```